# Dropdown list isn't shown correctly! Why?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, button, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

While clicking on the dropdown-list-button the dropdown list opens up but isn't shown correctly. Anybody has an idea to fix this?

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">
     Checked option            
     <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><input type="radio" id="ID" name="NAME" value="VALUE">
       <label for="ID">Label</label>
    </li>
     <!-- Other items -->
   </ul>
</div>
```

And I'm including these two Bootstrap files:

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: It works fine when using [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/AYcyMRjZA7). But why use a radio select here? It's unnecessary.

Comment: your css class might be missing -- ".dropdown-toggle"

Comment: @Andre - u r missing bootstrap-select.min.css -- its working here http://jsfiddle.net/hj152mge/23/

Comment: @ Friso van Dijk thx for your quick answer, yes you're right we get the same result, but normally i should get/(will have ;D) this result here (scroll down until it says Radio & Checkboxes > Usage > and than the dropdown menu wehere "option 1" is selected) -> http://behigh.github.io/bootstrap_dropdowns_enhancement/

Comment: You need to add their custom CSS [dropdowns-enhancement.css](http://behigh.github.io/bootstrap_dropdowns_enhancement/css/dropdowns-enhancement.css) for the styling. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/k07b9jc9/)

Answer (score 0):

Like the others, here's a working example: http://codepen.io/emaildano/pen/zxopNj

Can you provide more detail on how this "isn't showing up correctly"?

If I had to guess you're referring to the width of the drop down. That's set to a `min-width` of 160px. Of course that can be changed.